# Running-Total for multiple Measures

Tags: cognos, cumulative-sum

Appreciate if anyone could advice how can I apply the Running-Total function for multiple measures?

I have 2 measures (Count) and (Revenue) by Month (Row) and Year (Column)

```
                              Product A                                                                        Product B     
                2014                         2015                                             2014                         2015
        Count | Revenue         Count | Revenue                         Count | Revenue         Count | Revenue
```

Jan           100
Feb           200
YTD          300
Mar           555
YTD          855

I tried with 
running-total (currentMeasure for [Month], [Year], [Product Type])

but there is error claims that currentMeasure is not supported for QueryPackage.

In case I interpreted the message wrong, appreciate for your advice how can I apply the running-total correctly for multiple measures.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your data source relational or dimensional?

Comment: relational... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**Count**

```
running-total([Count] for [Product Type],[Year])
```

**Revenue**

```
running-total([Revenue] for [Product Type],[Year])
```

You don't specify month because it is in the row header. The 'for' clause indicates the grouping and the grouping comes from the column headers while the month defines the row grain. Another way to think about it is to put it into English:

*Within each Product Type and Year combination, show me the accumulating total of each succeeding row broken out by Month.*

Also, currentMeasure is used only in dimensionally-sourced reports, I believe.